# How to open a pdf file which is in views or controller folder in ci?

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, model-view-controller, codeigniter-2

i have a pdf file in view folder and controller folder by the link i need to access it how to do this i have tried with following by am getting error like
`Access forbidden!`

```
$path=base_url()."application/views/users/sample_pdf_report.pdf";
$path2="C:\xampp\htdocs\vacationgod\application\views\users\sample_pdf_report.pdf"
// OPTIONAL - PUT A LINK TO DOWNLOAD THE PDF YOU JUST CREATED
echo ("<a href='$path2'>Download Your PDF</a>");
```

i have tried both `$path and $path2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a .htaccess file forbidding people to access files in those folders.

You should create a res folder in your site root path and place your pdf file in that folder and link the file from there..

Happy coding :)